# Backbone.js send a GET request only once?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, socket.io

```
socket.on('new message', function(data) {
    self.createMessage(data);
}); 

createMessage: function(data) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.App.data.messages.fetch({
            success: function() {
                console.log('success')
            }
        });
    }, 1000); 
    window.App.core.vent.trigger('app:log', 'Chat View: Received a new message!');
}
```

Let's say for example I have three sockets/users connected. When I run the code above each client makes that GET request three times (as many users that are connected). A bit annoying to me, it works well but I don't like the unnecessary requests.

It's a bit confusing because if I just appended some HTML like this.

```
createMessage: function(data) {
    this.$el.find('.message-content').append('<div class="message"><b>'+data.username+':</b>'+data.message+'</div>');
    window.App.core.vent.trigger('app:log', 'Chat View: Received a new message!');
}
```

Then that only happens once across all connected sockets/users not three times? But when I fetch GET then it want's to make that request three times, hmm? Any ideas, what am I  missing?

**Full Code:** *So there is no confusion*

```
var Marionette = require('backbone.marionette'),
    MessagesView = require('./messages'),
    socket = io.connect();

module.exports = ChatView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

    className: 'chat',

    template: require('../../templates/chat.hbs'),

    events: { 
        'submit #chat-form': 'sendMessage' 
    },                

    initialize: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.messagesView = new MessagesView({ collection: window.App.data.messages });
        socket.on('new message', function(data) {
            self.createMessage(data);
        }); 
    },    

    onRender: function() {
        this.$el.find('.message-content').append(this.messagesView.render().$el);
    },

    sendMessage: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $message = this.$el.find('input.message');
            $email = this.$el.parent().attr('data-email');
            $username = this.$el.parent().attr('data-username');
        var message = {
            email   : $email,
            username: $username,
            message : $message.val()
        }
        if($message.val() != '') {
            socket.emit('send message', $message.val());
            window.App.data.messages.create(message);
            $message.val('');
        }
        window.App.core.vent.trigger('app:log', 'Chat View: Sent a new message!');
    },

    createMessage: function(data) {
        window.App.data.messages.fetch({
            success: function() {
                console.log('success')
            }
        }); 
        //this.$el.find('.message-content').append('<div class="message"><b>'+data.username+':</b>'+data.message+'</div>');
        window.App.core.vent.trigger('app:log', 'Chat View: Received a new message!');
    }

});
```

Comment: Must not be a hot topic lol

Comment: I don't see any GET requests here, but you might be duplicating your listeners.

Comment: Well the `.fetch` method makes a GET request. I found a solution :) Ill share here in a second!!

Comment: As for why it made the request three times, Im still puzzled, but by adding a callback to the POST method it solved that issue. Win-win

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the socket.io and backbone.js combination doesn't seem to popular. It's amazing technology IMO.

Okay so I found a solution, I forgot that while `.fetch` makes my GET requests, `.create` makes the POST request.

So by simply adding a call back to the `.create` method then on success I emit the data to the sockets, then return it to the client and make a GET request to all the sockets. Works like a charm, here is my solution.

```
var Marionette = require('backbone.marionette'),
    MessagesView = require('./messages'),
    socket = io.connect();

module.exports = ChatView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

    className: 'chat',

    template: require('../../templates/chat.hbs'),

    events: { 
        'submit #chat-form': 'sendMessage' 
    },                

    initialize: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.messagesView = new MessagesView({ collection: window.App.data.messages });
        socket.on('new message', function(data) {
            self.createMessage(data);
        }); 
    },    

    onRender: function() {
        this.$el.find('.message-content').append(this.messagesView.render().$el);
    },

    sendMessage: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $message = this.$el.find('input.message');
            $email = this.$el.parent().attr('data-email');
            $username = this.$el.parent().attr('data-username');
        var message = {
            email   : $email,
            username: $username,
            message : $message.val()
        }
        if($message.val() != '') {
            //window.App.data.messages.create(message);
            window.App.data.messages.create({ message }, {
                success: function() {
                    socket.emit('send message', $message.val());
                }
            });
            $message.val('');
        }
        window.App.core.vent.trigger('app:log', 'Chat View: Sent a new message!');
    },

    createMessage: function(data) {
        window.App.data.messages.fetch({
            success: function() {
                console.log('success')
            }
        }); 
        window.App.core.vent.trigger('app:log', 'Chat View: Received a new message!');
    }

});
```

This solves all my issues. For one I don't make an emission or any GET requests until the data is successfully on the server. Then after success I emit the data and then the `.fetch()` method only runs once for each socket!